# postgresql display two sublists in one result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Assuming the very simple schema

table main

```
main_id, ...
1      , ...
2      , ...
```

table sub1

```
main_id, sub1_data
1      , a
1      , b
2      , g
```

table sub2

```
main_id, sub2_data
1      , 1
2      , 1
2      , 2
```

As output I would like

```
main_id, sub1_data, sub2_data
1      , a        , 1
1      , b        , <null>
2      , g        , 1
2      , <null>   , 2
```

Using a union I can get close but then each list get's it's own rows

```
SELECT main_id, sub1_data, NULL
FROM sub1
UNION 
SELECT main_id, NULL, sub2_data
FROM sub2
```

result

```
main_id, sub1_data, sub2_data
1      , a        , <null>
1      , b        , <null>
1      , <null>   , 1
2      , g        , <null>
2      , <null>   , 1
2      , <null>   , 2
```

So is there a way to get them two share rows and just use as many rows as the longest list?

Comment: The value `g` should be associated with both records in your expected output.  Can you elaborate on the logic behind your output?

Comment: No real logic, only third party requirement to put it in a single CSV.

Comment: I think @TimBiegeleisen is asking not about reasonability, but about the algorithm we should follow to get your sample

Comment: @VaoTsun Correct, that's why I was asking.  It isn't a full outer join, so I was wondering what is the logic to arrive at his expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing which can give you this "interleaved" output is the [`unnest()` function with multiple parameters (or its equivalent: the `ROWS FROM(...)` construct)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS):

> Table functions may also be combined using the `ROWS FROM` syntax, with the results returned in parallel columns; the number of result rows in this case is that of the largest function result, with smaller results padded with null 
>   values to match.
>   ...
>   The special table function `UNNEST` may be called with any number of array parameters, and it returns a corresponding number of columns, as if `UNNEST`  had been called on each parameter separately and combined using the `ROWS FROM` construct.

```
select     main_id, sub1_data, sub2_data
from       (select main_id, array_agg(sub1_data) sub1_arr from sub1 group by main_id) s1
full join  (select main_id, array_agg(sub2_data) sub2_arr from sub2 group by main_id) s2 using (main_id)
cross join unnest(sub1_arr, sub2_arr) u(sub1_data, sub2_data)
```

http://rextester.com/QSWESJ84203

*Note*: this is a "relatively" new feature: it was introduced in 9.4